# Join in Laravel 8 not returning desired columns

Tags: laravel, join

Hi I am using Laravel 8 and have two tables Products and Categories. Both tables have name column. when i run the following query as join it returns categories.name but not products.name. where am I making mistake.

```
return  $product = DB::table('categories')
    ->join('products', 'products.category_id','=', 'categories.id')
    ->select('products.name','categories.name','products.price','products.description','categories.id','products.category_id')
    ->get();
  return view('products.single',compact('product'));
```

Result of the above query is

```
[{“name":"Category First","price":"742.00","description":"Distinctio Sapiente","id":1,"category_id":1},{"name":"Category First","price":"275.00","description":"Nobis velit totam a","id":1,"category_id":1},{"name":"Category First","price":"242.00","description":"Duis incidunt qui c","id":1,"category_id":1}]
```

Comment: My question would be, why isn't this just `$product = Category::with('products');`?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to display one product only with category name.

Comment: I don't see any filtering in your code here. You are pulling the entire `categories` table and joining the `products` table in. If you want one product with category, why not `$product = Product::find($id);`? Category would be `$product->category->name`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. I did try the same way first but I could not get category->name. and got error on name property. in my Product Model i have made a function public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);

    }

Comment: That should work; did you define the reverse relationship? I would be looking at that problem instead of working around it with query builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When two tables have a column with the same name you have to use an alias, something like this:

```
->select('products.name','categories.name AS category','products.price','products.description','categories.id','products.category_id')
```

Comment: Thanks for quick and accurate answer. it worked for me. Also I am displaying this data in a table in a single product view like <td>{{$product[0]->name}}</td>. Is there any other best way to display it or i will have to select each property of this array one by one. on products view i am using foreach loop though

Comment: You have to select each property to display it.